# Matrix Sparsity Pattern

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices

Suppose I have a matrix $H^{+} = (H^T H)^{-1} H^T$ where $H$ is a sparse matrix. Consider the case where only the sparsity pattern i.e. the zero elements of $H^{+}$ matrix is known, then would it be possible to infer the sparsity pattern or any other information of the $H$ matrix in either a deterministic or a probabilistic sense?

Comment: Presumably $H$ has full column rank, since $(H^T H)^{-1}$ exists.  If $H$ is a square matrix, $H^+ = H^{-1}$.  But the inverse of an invertible sparse matrix is likely to be dense.

Comment: Since $H^+ H = I$, for each $i$ there is some $j$ such that $(H^+)_{ij} \ne 0$ and $H_{ji} \ne 0$.